# Python csv reader ignore delimiters within double quotes that are part of a string

Tags: python, csv

If I have a string

```
s = 'some data in here, some more data in here, 0, a string|12345|"today,tomorrow-nextweek 6a-10a"|1234567, 2, 3.4, data string, string'
```

How do I read it in such that the result is this?

```
['some data in here',
 'some more data in here',
 '0',
 'a string|12345|"today,tomorrow-nextweek 6a-10a"|1234567',
 '2',
 '3.4',
 'data string',
 'string']
```

The element `'a string|12345|"today,tomorrow-nextweek 6a-10a"|1234567'` keeps getting broken into two elements by the csv reader because there are double quotes with another delimiter in between the delimiters. I am unsure if there is a way to resolve this with csv.reader. I have tried the following on the string already to no avail

```
next(csv.reader(StringIO(s), quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL, skipinitialspace=True))

next(csv.reader(StringIO(s), skipinitialspace=True))

next(csv.reader(StringIO(s), doublequote=True, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, escapechar='\\', skipinitialspace=True))
```

Comment: Do you control the source of this string? Python's `csv` module does not support any dialect with partially-quoted fields.

Comment: unfortunately, I am at the mercy of an api from a company who is providing the data

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with the dialects supported by the `csv` module. You can instead use `re.findall` with an alternation pattern that matches a repetition of either a double-quoted string or a non-comma character, with preceding positive lookahead pattern to ensure that the match starts with a non-whitespace:

```
import re
re.findall(r'(?=\S)(?:"[^"]*"|[^,])+', s)
```

Demo: https://repl.it/@blhsing/SplendidRichPyramid